# Login and user is not there IN SQL Server 2017 then why in T-SQL it shows up?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a login `metamanager\test` which shows when I execute T-SQL, but it is not there when when I expand `Security -> Login` in SSMS.

Same with a database user.

I try to replicate but failed

```
use master
select * from sys.syslogins is used for login

use DB
select * from sys.sysusers is used for database user
```

Comment: What do you get when you run these scripts and what you expect?

Comment: I except if there is a login which I can see when I expand instance level security-> login then the login should also show when I execute the script  select * from sys.syslogins. But here the scenario is different . I can't see a login metamanager\testlogin  when expand instance level security->login but can see the same login when execute the tsql  select * from sys.syslogins

Comment: You "can" or "can't" ?

Comment: can not find the login in instance but can see the login the execute the tsql

Comment: Have I answered your problem?

Comment: Actually I am not too old in this domain. So I thought if there is 100 login in instance secuirity->login, then it should shows 100 rows when i execute select * from sys.syslogins. And also Microsoft doc says "Contains one row for each login account" for this tsql. But mismatch happen. My confusion is not clear.And one more thing what is the difference between sys.syslogins and sys.server_principals both shows login name.  But thanks for your time.

Comment: sys.server_principals has records which sys.syslogins does not have. Was that your question?

Comment: No my question is if a real user login named supposed metamanager\slavaM is available in tsql select * from sys.syslogins then why it is not there when I expand instance level security->login

Comment: If you restore a database from another server it may contain users that aren't mapped to logins on the current server. That's esp. confusing when the user name and login name are equal.

Answer (score 2):

A `LOGIN` and a `USER` are completely different objects.

A `LOGIN` is a server object, and appear in `sys.syslogins`, as you see.

A `USER` is a database object, and for a `LOGIN` to have access to a database, it needs to have a `USER` mapped to the `LOGIN` in that database. A `LOGIN` with no mapped logins in any databases, and without any server level roles, will be unable to access any of the database on the instance, apart from those that the `public` roles has in `tempdb` and `master`.

It appears, here, you need to create the user in the database, and then give it the appropriate permissions. You can create the `USER` with the following:

```
USE {YourDatabase};
GO

CREATE USER 'metamanager\test' FOR LOGIN 'metamanager\test';
```

You'll need to give it the appropriate permissions afterwards.

Also, after you have created the user, ensure you have refreshed your object explorer. Object explorer doesn't automatically refresh after you create an object.

Comment: I know what you are talking about.May be I am unable to make you understand my concern. when I expand instance level security and go to login there i can't find a login named metamanager\testlogin but when I execute the tsql  select * from sys.syslogins  I can see the login metamanager\testlogin. How it is possible?

Comment: See my closing comment, @Rahul: *"Also, after you have created the user, ensure you have refreshed your object explorer. Object explorer doesn't automatically refresh after you create an object."*

Comment: Ok just just forget about the database user. I newly joined a organization.First day I just observed the sql server and do nothing. In a instance there is no login named metamanager\sroy when I expand the instance level security->login   but the same login is available when I execute select * from sys.syslogins. How it is possible? @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you explaining it correctly, but syslogins and server_principals are about the same. Only the difference that server_principals include "Roles". 
As far as I know it is impossible to have something in syslogins, which does not exist in server_principals.

Comment: I understand these query. You just filter some system predefined login. But The login which I want to mention that is a real user login metamanager\sroy  where domain=metamanager and the user is surajit roy. this login is not there in instance->security-> login but when execute  select * from sys.syslogins I can see the  metamanager\sroy. Hope you understand my concern.

Comment: are your name & loginname in syslogins the same?

Comment: Is your principal_id from syslogins matches any record in server_principals?

Comment: There is no principal_id column in syslogins table

Comment: Sorry, I've meant SID

Comment: That I did not check. Will check and let you know. Thank you so much for your help. It is really appreciable. Thanks a lot